# Draw Border along the cutting edges of a UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios9, calayer

I have a UIView with rounded corners along TopLeft and Bottom Right corner sides implement using this code.

```
CGFloat cornerRadius = _emailContainerView.frame.size.height/2;

CGRect bounds = _emailContainerView.bounds;
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

_emailContainerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But whenever i tried to draw a border either on the `_emailContainerView.layer.borderWidth` it shows the border but not along the cutting edges. It just remover the border from the rounded corner sides.
I want to draw the border right along the cutting edges is their any simple way to do that?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36411924/2976878)

Comment: @originaluser2 thank you sir it fixes my issue.